# How can I set a custom date time format in Oracle SQL Developer?

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

By default, Oracle SQL developer displays date values as `15-NOV-11`. I would like to see the time part (hour/minute/second) by default.

Is there a way to configure this within Oracle SQL Developer?

Comment: I've hard trouble with this before. I can correct it for a session, but once I close SQL Developer and then restart it again, I lose the setting. So this solution I can provide is not permanent.

Comment: Can you add it an answer? @BrettWalker, it's better than nothing.

Comment: What a ridiculous default for a data type called "DATE" that actually stores precision to the second.  This must have wasted a lot of people's time.

Answer (score 460, accepted):

You can change this in preferences:

1. From Oracle SQL Developer's menu go to: *Tools* > *Preferences*.
2. From the *Preferences* dialog, select *Database* > *NLS* from the left panel.
3. From the list of NLS parameters, enter `DD-MON-RR HH24:MI:SS` into the *Date Format* field.
4. Save and close the dialog, done!

Here is a screenshot:

[image: Changing Date Format preferences in Oracle SQL Developer]

Comment: I'm using SQLDeveloper on linux and this setting doesn't work for me.. any other way?

Comment: No matter what format I put there, it is getting ignored. I see this getting generated in the sql: to_date('02-OCT-14','YYYY-MM-DD') so now my sql is just plain broken.

Comment: this format does not worked for me, maybe because of platform locale differences ... see my answer if this one does not work

Comment: where is this setting stored? in the DB or SQL Developer?

Answer (score 57):

I stumbled on this post while trying to change the display format for dates in sql-developer. Just wanted to add to this what I found out:

- To Change the default display format, I would use the steps provided by ousoo i.e Tools > Preferences > ...
- But a lot of times, I just want to retain the DEFAULT_FORMAT while modifying the format only during a bunch of related queries. That's when I would change the format of the session with the following:

  `alter SESSION  set NLS_DATE_FORMAT = 'my_required_date_format'`

Eg:

```
   alter SESSION set NLS_DATE_FORMAT = 'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS'
```

Answer (score 38):

With Oracle SQL Developer 3.2.20.09, i managed to set the custom format for the type DATE this way :

In : Tools > Preferences > Database > NLS

Or : Outils > Préférences > Base de donées > NLS

> YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS

[image: Settings Menu screenshot]

Note that the following format **does not worked** for me :

> DD-MON-RR HH24:MI:SS

As a result, it keeps the default format, without any error.

Answer (score 8):

In my case the format set in Preferences/Database/NLS
was [Date Format] = RRRR-MM-DD HH24:MI:SSXFF
but in grid there were seen 8probably default format RRRR/MM/DD (even without time)
The format has changed after changing the setting [Date Format] to:
RRRR-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS
(without 'XFF' at the end).

There were no errors, but format with xff at the end didn't work.

Note: in polish notation RRRR means YYYY

Comment: TL;DR: **without 'XFF' at the end**

Comment: In Oracle, a date does NOT have a fractional seconds part.
A timestamp does.

So, Oracle is trying to be helpful by not letting you specify something that won't work.

Answer (score 4):

For anyone still having an issue with this; I happened to find this page from Google...

Put it in like this (NLS Parameters)... it sticks for me in SQLDeveloper v3.0.04:

```
DD-MON-YY HH12:MI:SS AM or for 24-Hour, DD-MON-YY HH24:MI:SS
```

Comment: It is important to note that the 'AM' format token is removed for the 24-hour format. If both the 'AM' and 'HH24' tokens are used, the 'AM' overrides the 'HH24'.

Answer (score 3):

SQL Developer Version 4.1.0.19

Step 1: Go to Tools -> Preferences

Step 2: Select Database -> NLS

Step 3: Go to Date Format and Enter    DD-MON-RR HH24: MI: SS

Step 4: Click OK.

Answer (score 0):

Goto to Tools > Preferences. In the tree, select Database > NLS. There are three Date/Time formats available: Date, Timestamp and Timestamp TZ. Editing the Date format gives the desired effect.

Like I have said above; this approach has not given me a permanent change.

Comment: jsyk , you profile pic reminds me om don corleone (wrong place for such comment)

Answer (score 0):

When i copied the date format for timestamp and used that for date, it did not work. But changing the date format to this (DD-MON-YY HH12:MI:SS AM) worked for me.

The change has to be made in Tools->Preferences-> search for NLS

Answer (score 0):

I have a related issue which I solved and wanted to let folks know about my solution. Using SQL Developer I exported from one database to csv, then tried to import it into another database. I kept getting an error in my date fields. My date fields were in the Timestamp format:

```
28-JAN-11 03.25.11.000000000 PM
```

The above solution (changing the NLS preferences) did not work for me when I imported, but I finally got the following to work:

In the Import Wizard Column Definition screen, I entered "`DD-MON-RR HH.MI.SSXFF AM`" in the Format box, and it finally imported successfully. Unfortunately I have dozens of date fields and to my knowledge there is no way to systematically apply this format to all date fields so I had to do it manually....sigh. If anyone knows a better way I'd be happy to hear it!