# Oracle date between and?

Tags: sql, oracle

Why is the results not include '2013-10-14'

```
select * 
  from table t 
 where t.f_date between to_date('2013-10-20', 'yyyy-mm-dd') and
                        to_date('2013-10-14', 'yyyy-mm-dd')
```

Comment: They probably do. Are you sure your date of '2013-10-14' doesn't have a time component? If you date is actually '2013-10-14 14:15', for example, it won't be selected. And some Oracle client tools will default to not showing the time component (SQL Developer, for example, doesn't display the time component "out of the box", though it [can be configured to](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8134493/how-can-i-set-a-custom-date-time-format-in-oracle-sql-developer).)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Does d.f_date include a time component? If it does, the only records that will be returned by `between` will be those whose time is *exactly* 00:00:00. All others will be greater that 2013-10-14.

When comparing dates, a date without a time component is assumed to have a 00:00:00 time component

Answer (score 1):

This could be caused by the time component issue mentioned in other answers, however you will also need to change your between to have the earliest date first, otherwise it will never return anything.

e.g.

```
SELECT *
FROM dual
WHERE SYSDATE BETWEEN SYSDATE AND SYSDATE + 1;
```

will return a 1 record, but

```
SELECT *
FROM dual
WHERE SYSDATE BETWEEN SYSDATE + 1 AND SYSDATE;
```

will not.