# Why wont TO_DATE return the TIME section of my query?

Tags: sql, oracle, epoch, to-date, to-char

I am trying to convert EPOCH to a HUMAN DATETIME.

- When I test this on their website, it returns the right value.
- When I do it within SQL Developer, it's wrong.

This lead me to check other basic SQL to see how they get returned,

```
select sysdate from dual = 12-OCT-2015
```

It's missing the time?

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(TO_DATE('2015/05/15 8:30:25', 'YYYY/MM/DD HH:MI:SS'))
FROM dual; 

= 15-MAY-15
```

Again its missing the time?

```
SELECT TO_DATE('2015/05/15 8:30:25', 'YYYY/MM/DD HH:MI:SS')
FROM dual; 

= 15-MAY-15
```

With out TO_CHAR, still missing time.

Then my EPOCH SQL,

```
SELECT TO_DATE('01/01/1970 00:00:00','DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS')+(1325289600000/60/60/24) AS EPOCH FROM dual;
```

> This should return: Sat, 31 Dec 2011 00:00:00 GMT but it returns:
>   04-OCT-30

Again, TIME is missing.

SERVER is on EST, so time is out by 5 hour
Oracle Server 11g
Using SQL DEveloper 4.0.2.15

Thanks for any help, 
Ben

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I set a custom date time format in Oracle SQL Developer?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8134493/how-can-i-set-a-custom-date-time-format-in-oracle-sql-developer)

Comment: It returns. But your local time format (for displaying) does not display it.

Comment: Your *epoch* includes milliseconds, you need to divide it by 1000: `1325289600000/1000/60/60/24`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your *epoch* includes milliseconds, you need to divide it by 1000:

```
SELECT TO_DATE('01/01/1970 00:00:00','DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS')
         +(1325289600000/1000/60/60/24) AS EPOCH
FROM dual;
```

Answer (score 2):

Mask should be in TO_CHAR function as well to output time.

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(TO_DATE('2015/05/15 8:30:25', 'YYYY/MM/DD HH:MI:SS'), 'YYYY/MM/DD HH:MI:SS')
FROM dual;
```

But it will be character string. If you want to do something with this date (add something and so on), you should put TO_CHAR last (first do everything with date, then put TO_CHAR with mask)

Comment: I ran your script above, it says SQL command not properly ended ??

**Scratch that, my bad Cut and paste!, it worked fine**

but you are right, its now a String.

Comment: Also, when added to my EPOCH query it returns zero, 

SELECT TO_CHAR(TO_DATE('01/01/1970 00:00:00','DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS')+(1325289600000/60/60/24),'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') AS EPOCH FROM dual;

Answer (score 2):

> Its missing the time?

No, it is there, you are just not displaying it. Or your client's locale-specific NLS settings are not correctly set to display the time portion.

A date always has both date and time portions, which is internally stored by Oracle in a 7-byte proprietary format.

At individual SQL level, to display a date in your desired format, always use **TO_DATE** along with the proper **FORMAT MODEL**.

For example,

**Session level**

```
SQL> alter session set nls_date_format='YYYY-MM-DD';

Session altered.

SQL> SELECT SYSDATE FROM DUAL;

SYSDATE
----------
2015-10-12

SQL> alter session set nls_date_format='YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS';

Session altered.

SQL> SELECT SYSDATE FROM DUAL;

SYSDATE
-------------------
2015-10-12 17:08:18
```

**Individual SQL level** Will override session and client's NLS settings:

```
SQL> SELECT TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'YYYY/MM/DD HH24:MI:SS') FROM DUAL;

TO_CHAR(SYSDATE,'YY
-------------------
2015/10/12 17:09:58
```

Answer (score 1):

It returns the correct value but SQL developer is not set up to display it correctly.

From [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8134646/1509264):

> You can change this in preferences:
>
> 1. From Oracle SQL Developer's menu go to: Tools > Preferences.
> 2. From the Preferences dialog, select Database > NLS from the left panel.
> 3. From the list of NLS parameters, enter `DD-MON-RR HH24:MI:SS` into the Date Format field.
> 4. Save and close the dialog, done!

(I prefer the ISO standard format `YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS` but whichever you prefer will work.)

Then if you do:

```
SELECT TO_DATE('01/01/1970 00:00:00','DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS')
         +(1325289600000/60/60/24) AS EPOCH
FROM dual;
```

The output for `DD-MON-RR HH24:MI:SS` format will be:

```
EPOCH            
------------------
04-OCT-30 00:00:00
```

and the output for `YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS` would be:

```
EPOCH             
-------------------
4030-10-04 00:00:00
```

Comment: Thank you for solving issue 1, i can now see the time value. However, the value is wrong. 1325289600000 should be 31-DEC-2011 00:00:00??

http://www.epochconverter.com/

Comment: `1325289600000/60/60/24` is `15339000` days which is `42024.65` years. Did you mean `SELECT TO_DATE('01/01/1970 00:00:00','DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') +(1325289600000/1000/60/60/24) AS EPOCH FROM dual;` instead?

Comment: Thank you, i was missing the milliseconds (/1000) to get the right level of conversion. Thank you very much!