# select sysdate from dual returns only date, not time

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

In SqlDeveloper, when I run this query:

```
select sysdate from dual
```

I see only 15-FEB-16,

but not the time portion. I suppose that there is time portion, but somehow I can not see it. How to fix this?

Thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8134493/how-can-i-set-a-custom-date-time-format-in-oracle-sql-developer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your NLS settings: Tools -> Preferences -> Database -> NLS

[Changing Default Date Format settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7KrGB.png)

Answer (score 4):

If you don't want/can't change the NLS settings, use the to_char function, but note that since then its a varchar type, not a date anymore! changing it back to date would display it according to NLS settings again

```
SELECT to_char(SYSDATE, 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mm:ss') from dual
```

this way you can define the format (using the mask) anyway you want