# change date format 'yyyy/mm/dd' to 'mm-dd-yyyy' in Oracle

Tags: oracle

I have inserted into a table in Oracle.  My implementation without PLSQL would be:

```
SELECT to_date('1900-01-01','YYYY-MM-DD') + (rownum - 1) AS DT_CAL, 
       rownum AS NUM_JOUR 
FROM   dual 
CONNECT BY to_date('1900-01-01','YYYY-MM-DD') + (rownum - 1) <= 
                                                      to_date('2000-12-31','YYYY-MM-DD')
```

result is: `05/28/1900`, not `1900-05-28`. Can you help me understand what the problem is?

Answer (score 1):

The `DATE` data type does not have a format; Oracle stores it as either [7- or 8-bytes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13568348/1509264) and it is not until it is passed to a client program (i.e. SQL/Plus, SQL Developer, Toad, Java, Python, etc) and that client program formats it according to whatever rules it has that the date gets a format.

If you are using SQL/Plus or SQL Developer then it will use the `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` session parameter to format the date. [You can change this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8134646/1509264) using:

[`ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DATE_FORMAT = 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS';`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16309763/1509264)

*(Be aware that this will only change the format in the current session and will not change it for any other sessions/users.)*

If you want to give the date a particular format then you will need to [convert it to a string](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions180.htm).

Comment: when i use to_char('2006-01-01','YYYY-MM-DD') i obtain this error:

Comment: ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected DATE got NUMBER

Comment: `'2006-01-01'` is a string literal and not a date. `DATE '2006-01-01'` is a date literal.

Comment: @mto Worked for me

Answer (score 0):

to_date() takes your string parameter, matches it to the format you provide in the second parameter, and constructs a date field from it.  The date field isn't using the format you provided in the second parameter - in fact it'll be stored using some internal data representation that has no format at all (a number, in all likelihood).

To present a format back out in the results from a date field, you can either:

1. Have the client executing the query set the NLS parameters (at session level) to provide a localized format, with an `ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DATE_FORMAT='YYYY-MM-DD';` statement), or
2. Use `to_char(..., 'YYYY-MM-DD')` around your existing field to turn the date back into a string formatted the way you want to have it.  Where you replace `...` with your current column definition in the select.

Approach #1 is already happening, as there'll already be an NLS_DATE_FORMAT set that is producing the current format, but it's with a format you don't want, so if you can control it and change it there, you can do it that way.  If you can't and you must have the format a single consistent other way, then #2 could be the way to go.

Comment: This is the correct answer. For "production" queries, it is always best to use to_char(DATE_COLUMN, '.....') with the desired date format model, since we can't control another user's NLS settings; but for the OP just checking results for him/herself, the NLS_DATE_FORMAT solution suffices. NOTE regarding the internal format Oracle uses for internal storing of dates: "BluShadow" at OTN has a good explanation. To find out for yourself, you can run SELECT DUMP(SYSDATE) FROM DUAL and try to understand it. It's not obvious - but it is not a number, it's seven numbers.

Comment: @mathguy The format of a date is also on [Stackoverflow documentation](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/oracle/2087/dates/6848/the-format-of-a-date#t=201607240002226712408).

Comment: @MT0   Excellent, thank you! I saw the ads for SO documentation but didn't bother to look into it yet. Great idea, likely to join the effort soon.