# oracle update date format mask

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have this procedure, i need birthday field to be in format 16-JUL-2018, but when i run procedure it is updated in 16-JUL-18 format.
How to update it in wanted format ?

```
PROCEDURE update_affiliate (pid                NUMBER,
                                   i_username         VARCHAR2,
                                   i_first_name       VARCHAR2,                              
                                   i_birthday         DATE)
       IS
       BEGIN
          UPDATE   affiliate_v
             SET   username = UPPER (i_username),
                   first_name = i_first_name,
                   birthday = TO_DATE(i_birthday,'DD-MON-YYYY'),
           WHERE   party_id = pid;

       END update_affiliate;
```

Comment: Its not the saving issue, as you think, but the SEEING issue. Well, its not an issue in the first place - the date is shown in format, depending on your NLS_DATE_FORMAT.

Comment: NLS_LANGUAGE AMERICAN
NLS_TERRITORY AMERICA
NLS_CURRENCY $
NLS_ISO_CURRENCY AMERICA
NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS .,
NLS_CALENDAR GREGORIAN
NLS_DATE_FORMAT DD-MON-RR
NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE AMERICAN
NLS_CHARACTERSET AL32UTF8
NLS_SORT BINARY
NLS_TIME_FORMAT HH.MI.SSXFF AM
NLS_TIMESTAMP_FORMAT DD-MON-RR HH.MI.SSXFF AM
NLS_TIME_TZ_FORMAT HH.MI.SSXFF AM TZR
NLS_TIMESTAMP_TZ_FORMAT DD-MON-RR HH.MI.SSXFF AM TZR
NLS_DUAL_CURRENCY $
NLS_NCHAR_CHARACTERSET AL16UTF16
NLS_COMP BINARY
NLS_LENGTH_SEMANTICS BYTE
NLS_NCHAR_CONV_EXCP FALSE

This is what i get when run select * fron V$nls_parameters

Comment: **NEVER**, ever call `to_date()` on a value that is already a date. That will first convert the `date` value to a `varchar` just to convert that `varchar` back to a `date` which it was to begin with.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You do not need to convert `i_birthday` to a `DATE` using `TO_DATE` as it is already a `DATE` data type. Just use:

```
PROCEDURE update_affiliate (
  pid                NUMBER,
  i_username         VARCHAR2,
  i_first_name       VARCHAR2,                              
  i_birthday         DATE)
IS
BEGIN
  UPDATE affiliate_v
  SET    username   = UPPER (i_username),
         first_name = i_first_name,
         birthday   = i_birthday,
  WHERE  party_id   = pid;
END update_affiliate;
```

> How to update it in wanted format?

This is a common misconception that dates in the database have a format.

A date does not have a format - it is [stored internally to the database as 7-bytes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13568348/1509264) (representing year, month, day, hour, minute and second) and it is not until whatever user interface you are using (i.e. SQL/Plus, SQL Developer, Java, etc) tries to display it to you, the user, and converts it into something you would find meaningful (usually a string) that the date is given a format so that you, the user, find it meaningful on the client software.

Since you are passing in a `DATE` you don't need to do anything.

What you probably want to ask is:

> Now I have updated the date, how can I get the user interface to display the date in the format I want when I query the table?

If you are using SQL/Plus or SQL Developer then it will use the `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` session parameter to format the date. You can [change this using](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38547559/1509264):

```
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DATE_FORMAT = 'DD-MON-YYYY';
```

Note: This is a session parameter and will only change the format for the current session (not for any other users or any subsequent sessions).

You can also change the preferences in the SQL Developer GUI as [described here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8134646/1509264).

Or you can just use `TO_CHAR` and set the format you want:

```
SELECT party_id,
       username,
       first_name,
       TO_CHAR( birthday, 'DD-MON-YYYY' ) AS birthday
FROM   affiliate_v
```

Comment: Yea you are right,  my colleague says that is gets in dd-mon-rr format just need to find what function displaying and change it to rrrr format.
Thanks on explanation..

Comment: @civesuas_sine Unfortunately, your colleague is not quite correct - it does not "get [the date] in [XYZ] format" or in any format - it just gets the 7 unformatted bytes and once it has the unformatted data the user interface you are using (SQL/Plus, SQL Developer, Java, etc) will apply its default format when it tries to display it. Your issue is that you do not want the default format and either need to change the default or, better, use `TO_CHAR` to explicitly set your desired format.

Comment: I m using TOAD and in nls parameters nls_date_format is set to dd-mon-rr.. I can change it there but its only valid for that session. How can i save it to stay that ?

Comment: @civesuas_sine The best solution is to modify your query to use `TO_CHAR` and explicitly set the format model so that you do not have to modify the session parameters (and so the output is consistent for all users who run the query). An alternate solution would be to set the `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` in a logon trigger (however this does not prevent someone changing the format later in the session and then your output will change).