# Oracle Date Matching

Tags: sql, oracle, date

I am trying to perform a bulk data update in an Oracle 12c database table, for records which match a range of dates. The dates have time information, so I'm using the `trunc()` function to strip the time component away. I can successfully perform a select query with this criteria, but somehow updates with the same where clause do not match the records. Anyone know what's going on?

```
select count(*) from TABLE_NAME
where TRUNC(DATE_FIELD) in ('30-Apr-13', '31-May-13', '31-Jul-13')
-- 554
```

However..

```
update TABLE_NAME set SOME_FIELD = 'VALUE'
where TRUNC(DATE_FIELD) in ('30-Apr-13', '31-May-13', '31-Jul-13')
-- 0 rows updated.
```

**--Edit--**

I also tried `to_date('30-Apr-13'), ...` to no effect.

Comment: Does the `SOME_FIELD` have any index (mainly UNIQUE)?

Comment: Can you add the DDL for the table and sample data (in a format that shows the full date/time)? Does using explicit conversions and format masks make any difference; and if so what is you NLS_DATE_FORMAT when you see this behaviour?

Comment: I could not reproduce the behaviour on 'Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.4.0 - 64bit Production'. I consider the behaviour to be strange. Is it a matter of someone else changing the data in the meantime?

Comment: Try ANSI date literals: `UPDATE table_name SET some_field = 'VALUE' WHERE TRUNC( date_field ) IN ( DATE '2013-04-30', DATE '2013-05-31', DATE '2014-07-31' )`

Comment: @AlexPoole you got it! i had to run the updates in an automated batch loader which had a different date format from my sql developer which i used for the selects. sorry, should have mentioned that. the updates were successful once i modified the year component to the full form i.e. 2013, 2014. do fill out an answer so i can mark it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It wasn't clear in the original question, but you're relying on implicit conversions between dates and strings, and running the query and updates in sessions with different default formats, via their `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` settings. To replicate the effect:

```
create table table_name (date_field date, some_field varchar2(5));

insert into table_name values (timestamp '2013-04-30 00:00:01', null);

alter session set nls_date_format = 'DD-MON-RR';

select count(*) from TABLE_NAME
where TRUNC(DATE_FIELD) in ('30-Apr-13', '31-May-13', '31-Jul-13');

  COUNT(*)
----------
         1

alter session set nls_date_format = 'DD-MON-YYYY';

update TABLE_NAME set SOME_FIELD = 'VALUE'
where TRUNC(DATE_FIELD) in ('30-Apr-13', '31-May-13', '31-Jul-13');

0 rows updated.
```

The implicit conversion is changing your truncated date column value to, for example, `'30-Apr-2013'`, which does not match the literal you're comparing with, `'30-Apr-13'`. With the version you added as an edit, comparing `to_date('30-Apr-13')`, that will be converted to the date `0013-04-30`, which still doesn't match the date `2013-04-30`.

You could still use string comparison but provide a four-digit year representation:

```
update TABLE_NAME set SOME_FIELD = 'VALUE'
where TRUNC(DATE_FIELD) in ('30-Apr-2013', '31-May-2013', '31-Jul-2013');

1 row updated.
```

It would usually be better to convert your strings to dates with an explicit format mask (four-digit years are better, but you *could* use two-digit if you're prepared for the risk of ambiguity):

```
update TABLE_NAME set SOME_FIELD = 'VALUE'
where TRUNC(DATE_FIELD) in (to_date('30-Apr-2013', 'DD-Mon-YYYY'),
  to_date('31-May-2013', 'DD-Mon-YYYY'), to_date('31-Jul-2013', 'DD-Mon-YYYY'));

1 row updated.

update TABLE_NAME set SOME_FIELD = 'VALUE'
where TRUNC(DATE_FIELD) in (to_date('30-Apr-13', 'DD-Mon-RR'),
  to_date('31-May-13', 'DD-Mon-RR'), to_date('31-Jul-13', 'DD-Mon-RR'));

1 row updated.
```

Or as they are fixed dates you could use shorter but unambiguous [date literals](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/sql_elements003.htm#SQLRF51062):

```
update TABLE_NAME set SOME_FIELD = 'VALUE'
where TRUNC(DATE_FIELD) in (date '2013-04-30', date '2013-05-31', date '2013-07-31');

1 row updated.
```

It's worth pointing out that doing `TRUNC(DATE_FIELD)` will prevent any index on that column being used, whatever you compare it with. You can compare with date ranges instead to avoid that, e.g.:

```
update TABLE_NAME set SOME_FIELD = 'VALUE'
where (DATE_FIELD >= date '2013-04-30' and DATE_FIELD < date '2013-05-01')
or (DATE_FIELD >= date '2013-05-31' and DATE_FIELD < date '2013-06-01')
or (DATE_FIELD >= date '2013-07-31' and DATE_FIELD < date '2013-08-01');
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [ANSI date literals](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/sql_elements003.htm#SQLRF51062) rather than relying on the [NLS_DATE_FORMAT parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16309763/1509264) to convert strings to dates:

```
UPDATE table_name
SET some_field = 'VALUE'
WHERE TRUNC( date_field ) IN ( DATE '2013-04-30', DATE '2013-05-31', DATE '2014-07-31' )
```