# Oracle SQL Developer, how DATE is stored?

Tags: java, oracle, date

I'm using oracle database with my java application. In DB i have created a table with column of type `DATE` and then my application populated this table with some dates with precision to seconds.

Now my application is able to retrieve date with precision to seconds and everything works fine. However I'm using `Oracle SQL Developer` to keep an eye on what is in the database, and here comes my problem, when I look inside my table from table view in column with `DATE` I can see only date in format of `16/09/07` without time of hours/minutes/seconds.

Also if I run a script:

```
select SAVED_DATE from MY_TABLE;
```

it returns all dates in format of `16/09/07` without time of hours/minutes/seconds.

How can I inspect from Oracle SQL Developer precise time stored in that column?

Comment: NLS format settings.  Tools --> preferences--> Database-->NLS set your date/timestamp format to be format desired, or use to_Char to format date to show time portions. `Select to_Char(sysdate,'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') from dual`  or see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8134493/how-can-i-set-a-custom-date-time-format-in-oracle-sql-developer) for more info  on NLS settings

Comment: @Jens Oracle has `DATE` and `TIMESTAMP` data types and **both** have a time component. Oracle does not have a separate `DATETIME` data type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [ixora](http://www.ixora.com.au/notes/date_representation.htm). On a contrary to other databases and also to Java, Oracle's `DATE` datatype also contains hours, minutes and seconds.

> byte 1: century + 100
>
> byte 2: year + 100
>
> byte 3: month
>
> byte 4: day of month
>
> byte 5: hour + 1
>
> byte 6: minute + 1
>
> byte 7: second + 1

What confuses you is an implicit datatype conversion to VARCHAR2. This is driven by session parameter `NLS_DATE_FORMAT`.

xQbert is right, change NLS_DATE_FORMAT in SQLDeveloper settings to "YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS".

Comment: thank you, explained everything.

Comment: @AkkaJaworek Dates not stored in a table (type 13) are 8-bytes and dates stored in tables (type 12) are 7-bytes - see [SO Documentation for the Format of a Date](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/oracle/2087/dates/6848/the-format-of-a-date) and the [SO Documentation for Setting the Default Format Model of a Date](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/oracle/2087/dates/6850/setting-the-default-date-format-model).

Answer (score 0):

A `Date` column in Oracle databases will store information with a precision down to seconds. The default returned data when selecting from this column will be `DD-MON-YY`.

It is possible to get the original precision by using `to_char` when selecting. For example:

`SELECT to_char(SAVED_DATE,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') FROM MY_TABLE`

will return a date like `2016-09-07 14:58:30`

Comment: is it possible that date retrived from database by java application has date with proper time of hours/minutes/seconds? This is example of what Hibernate returns me when i ask for date from database ``2016-09-07 11:24:55.0``

Comment: Once the data has been stored in a `Date` field, there is no way to retrieve the original data with a precision smaller than days.

Comment: Not in oracle.  Oracle stores the time portion on a date data type:  See this example: `create table foo (
mDate date,
mtimestamp timestamp);

insert into foo values (to_date('2016-1-1 15:23:33', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'),sysdate);
Select A.*, to_char(mdate,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') from foo A;`

Comment: Ah look at that, Looks like I misread my source. I'll update the answer