# Date is not taking proper format as Expected (dd/MM/yyyy)

Tags: c#, asp.net, date, datetime

I want to insert date into database in `dd/MM/yyyy` format. For that I have written like below:

```
drExpInfo[0]["CHEQUE_DT"] = string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(e.Record["CHEQUE_DT"].ToString())
    ? DBNull.Value : (object)Convert.ToDateTime(e.Record["CHEQUE_DT"]);
```

And it is working perfectly fine on my local machine, but on my server it is taking format as `dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss`. So how to set the same format there too. Kindly suggest.

Comment: What DBMS are you using? And what type is `CHEQUE_DT` in db?

Comment: @M.Wiśnicki: I am using `Oracle` sorry forgot to tag that. and `cheque_dt` is date datatype

Comment: Don't store dates as a *string* that *has* a format. Store them in an appropriate data type in your database (e.g. `datetime`). Such types don't *have* formats.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever; thanks for the suggestion. I am using `date` in db. I just want to customize here in my code. how to handle it here

Comment: So, immediately after the date is input, parse it into a .NET `DateTime`. Then, use parameters when sending it *to* the database (and rely on ADO.Net and the ODP to perform appropriate transforms to Oracle's `date`) and retrieve it back from the database back into a `DateTime` and, only at the point of actually displaying it back to the user should you transform it back into a string. At that point, you can pick whatever format you like - but it's translating it (inappropriately) into strings when you don't *need* a string that **leads** to formatting errors.

Comment: The question appears to be about C#'s formatting of dates as strings (or, if more properly implemented, passing a date to a parameterized SQL query) and the database being used is tangential to the question (i.e. the same technique will be used regardless of the RDBMS). As such, I've removed the Oracle tag. If you decide to edit the question include the SQL query to actually make it RDBMS specific then you can reapply the tag.

Answer (score 1):

Use [DateTime.ToShortDateString](https://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev14.query?appId=Dev14IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(System.DateTime.ToShortDateString);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.6.2);k(DevLang-csharp)&rd=true):

```
drExpInfo[0]["CHEQUE_DT"] = string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(e.Record["CHEQUE_DT"].ToString())
    ? DBNull.Value : (object)Convert.ToDateTime(e.Record["CHEQUE_DT"]).ToShortDateString();
```

But, I suggest you keep the time part of your date (without using the ToShortDateString as it will insert a time set to midnight, cf. highlighted text in Oracle documentation below) when inserting and get the format you want (without time) when you're using the date.

From [Oracle documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e10729/ch4datetime.htm#NLSPG238):

> Oracle Database automatically converts character values that are in the default date format into date values when they are used in date expressions.
>
> **If you specify a date value without a time component, then the default time is midnight.** If you specify a date value without a date, then the default date is the first day of the current month.
>
> Oracle Database DATE columns always contain fields for both date and time. If your queries use a date format without a time portion, then you must ensure that the time fields in the DATE column are set to midnight. You can use the TRUNC (date) SQL function to ensure that the time fields are set to midnight, or you can make the query a test of greater than or less than (<, <=, >=, or >) instead of equality or inequality (= or !=). Otherwise, Oracle Database may not return the query results you expect.

So you can convert you're date in any format you want in c#, removing the time part, Oracle will automatically set the time part of your date as midnight (00:00:00).

Comment: Because your oracle type is a date, so it should insert the time part as 00:00:00. Am I correct? I suggest you keep the time part.

Comment: No, It is showing in db too that is why i dont want it

Comment: I updated my answer with Oracle references and suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
public static DateTime? DateFromString(string value)
{
   if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(value))
     {
       return null;
     }
   else
     {
        return DateTime.ParseExact(dateString, "dd/MM/yyyy", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
     }
}

DateTime? date=DateFromString(e.Record["CHEQUE_DT"]);
drExpInfo[0]["CHEQUE_DT"] = date==null? DBNull.Value : (object)date);
```

Comment: The best overload method has some invalid arguments at line `DateTime? date= DateFromString(e.Record["CHEQUE_DT"];`

Answer (score 0):

You can set CultureInfo;

```
var cultureInfo = new CultureInfo("en-GB", false).DateTimeFormat;
string result = Convert.ToDateTime(e.Record["CHEQUE_DT"], cultureInfo).ToString();
```

Comment: sorry I didnt try code. But you can add ToString() or result as var

Comment: I also need to check for NULL also. if no date is provided then your code will throw an error

Answer (score 0):

[Check this Discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8134493/how-can-i-set-a-custom-date-time-format-in-oracle-sql-developer)
Here you can find two or more ways to setting date format while insert records into database.

```
insert into sampleDate(Start_Date) values (to_date('25-Jun-2017','YYYYMMDD'))
```

Comment: insert into sampleDate(Start_Date)  values (to_date('25-Jun-2017','YYYYMMDD'))

Comment: This is a link only answer; it should be a comment on the question or include the relevant parts in the answer. However, the linked question relates to SQL Developer and not to formatting dates in C# and appears to only be tangentially relevant.

Comment: @Kathir07 You can edit and improve your answer instead of commenting it.