# Data Export From SQL Developer to CSV

Tags: oracle, csv, oracle-sqldeveloper, export-to-csv

When exporting the oracle DB result set to CSV file using SQL developer, for the fields which are having date format, will not be saved in date format in CSV.

What I need is to have the date format for date fields in CSV as well. But when export data to CSV the date fields will get in General format. I can't change the General Format into Date in exported CSV.

Answer (score 1):

1. change the `DATE`fromat in SQL Developer as required - see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8134493/how-can-i-set-a-custom-date-time-format-in-oracle-sql-developer)
2. run the query that provides the data to be exported in `csv` (you sould see the dates in the required format!)
3. in the result are per right mouse click select export and choose format `csv`; add other parameter as required.

Comment: I did the same thins and still I couldn’t get the Date as Date Format.It comes as general format. I want to it change comes as Date into excel or csv file.