# SQL DEV doesn't show full DATE

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I use Oracle SQL Developer and Query Result doesn't return me full date. Also the same format (yyyy/mm/dd) in *table -> data*. How to fix this? I didnt find any option which would help.

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I set a custom date time format in Oracle SQL Developer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8134493/how-can-i-set-a-custom-date-time-format-in-oracle-sql-developer)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's just formatting issue.  Goto "Tools->Preferences->Database->NLS" , set Date Format to something like "YYYY-MM-DD hh24:mi:ss" .

or you can run `ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DATE_FORMAT = 'YYYY-MM-DD hh24:mi:ss'`

Comment: or include the date format you want in your query, that way app/nls parameters won't matter

Comment: @thatjeffsmith : surely, `to_char` always work, but it will be a slight difference - in this case column  value comes to client as string , not as datetime. That in turn might cause some client(e.g. SQLDeveloper ) functionality "misbehave".  Say sorting data in grid by string column formatted as "DD-MM-YYYY hh24:mi:ss" is very different from sorting the same data by datetime column .

Comment: i'm saying if you're doing up a report - don't leave date formats to chance

Answer (score 1):

That's because the default behaviour of SQL Developer is to ony show the date part. Try forcing the output to be displayed as a datetime string this way

```
select  id, id_player, id_map, x, y, to_char(time, 'yyyy/mm/dd hh24:mi:ss')
from LOGI
```

Comment: At least a real answer. I don't understand why the first one has been selected as a "DATE" column will ALWAYS be displayed as a ... (short) date... Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

This is due to your NLS_DATE_FORMAT settings, which decide how a date is displayed on the client.

To change it permanently,

Go to `Tool -> Preference -> Database -> NLS` and set date format to `YYYY/MM/DD HH24:MI:SS` or whatever you want.