# Date format in where clause match date format from table

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

I'm using previously written scripts that have the date format in the WHERE clause as 'DD-MMM-YY', however, in the table it is formatted as 'DD-MMM-YY HH.MM.SS.000000000 AM/PM. Does it matter that these formats do not match up? After comparing results it doesn't seem like any data is missing using non-matching formats. Wasn't sure if efficiency would be different if they matched or didn't match? Just let me know your thoughts and opinions. Thanks all!

Answer (score 1):

Your `where` clause is fine. The table formatting is just a representation of the date. You can change this if it helps you view the results more easily (see link below), but it will make no difference to the efficiency of the query.

[How can I set a custom date time format in Oracle SQL Developer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8134493/how-can-i-set-a-custom-date-time-format-in-oracle-sql-developer)