# How to convert values from 2 different hour and minute column in ti time stamp or char in single column in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I have values in 2 different columns like this

[image: Column picture]

How do I gather it in to one single column like this

```
Result_column
14:08
09:36
19:07
11:11
```

Date will remain in its separate column. How to achieve this. 
I  want to do this becoz I have time in other table in this format `19:11:38`
and I want to compare both.

Answer (score 0):

Use a group of **[`CONCAT`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions026.htm)** function.

**Query**

```
select 
concat(
    concat(
        case when click_hr < 10 
        then concat('0', cast(click_hr  as varchar(100))) 
        else cast(click_hr as varchar(100)) end,
       ':')
   , case when click_min < 10 
   then concat('0', cast(click_min as varchar(100))) 
   else cast(click_min as varchar(100)) end) as result
from your_table_name;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need the resultant value to be in time format i.e. `hh:mi:ss`, below could be an option.

```
SELECT click_date,
       to_char(to_Date(click_hr || to_char(click_min, '09') || 00, 'hh24miss'), 'hh24:mi:ss') AS TIME
FROM table1
```

**Result:**

```
CLICK_DATE              TIME
--------------------------------
17.10.2017 00:00:00     14:08:00
19.10.2017 00:00:00     09:36:00
24.10.2017 00:00:00     19:07:00
```

**[DEMO](http://rextester.com/AAX96073)**

Answer (score 0):

A [`DATE` data type always has a year, month, day, hour, minute and second components](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13568193/1509264) - your [IDE is probably just not showing them to you](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8134493/1509264).

Do not store the values as separate columns, store them in the date:

```
CREATE TABLE table_name( click_date ) AS
SELECT TO_DATE( '2017-10-10 14:08:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS' ) FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT TO_DATE( '2017-10-19 09:36:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS' ) FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT TO_DATE( '2017-10-24 19:07:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS' ) FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT TO_DATE( '2017-09-29 11:11:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS' ) FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT TO_DATE( '2017-10-02 18:18:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS' ) FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT TO_DATE( '2017-09-27 12:08:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS' ) FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT TO_DATE( '2017-10-05 10:37:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS' ) FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT TO_DATE( '2017-10-05 11:43:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS' ) FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT TO_DATE( '2017-10-14 12:41:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS' ) FROM DUAL;
```

Then you can just do:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR( click_date, 'HH24:MI' ) AS time
FROM   table_name
```

or, to get the value as an interval:

```
SELECT click_date - TRUNC( click_date ) AS time
FROM   table_name
```

With your current table structure you can get an interval as:

```
SELECT NUMTODSINTERVAL( click_hr, 'HOUR' )
       + NUMTODSINTERVAL( click_min, 'MINUTE' ) AS time
FROM   table_name
```

Or, as a string:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR( click_hr, '00' ) || ':' || TO_CHAR( click_min, '00' ) AS time
FROM   table_name
```