# SQL Developer not displaying Time of a DATE column - but NLS is set

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

I have a problem with sqldeveloper version 17.4 when the data grid is displaying columns of type DATE.

The only thing the data grid is showing me is DD.MON.RR while I would also like to see HH24:MI:SS

- I found several answers telling me to set the values in Tools -> Preferences -> Database -> NLS

The setting there is set to DD.MON.RR HH24:MI:SS but still the data grid is not showing me the exact value, even a query does the same (but the data really contains that information, I have checked that with TOAD).

Does anybody experience the same problem or have a solution?

Comment: That setting is honoured in the grid for me with that version. What do you see in the worksheet if you run the same query? Do you maybe have 'skip NLS settings' ticked, so the text boxes where you can change the setting are disabled?

Comment: @AlexPoole The skip NLS setting is not ticked. When I run the query in the worksheet I also don't see the timestamp for it.

Comment: I don't see how to replicate this in 17.4 (or any version), in grid or worksheet. Your reference to 'timestamp' is slightly confusing though; are you looking at the NLS setting for 'Date Format' or for 'Timestamp Format'? Only the 'Date Format' will be applied to a DATE column. (Kind of stating the obvious but that's the only thing I can think you might be doing wrong...)

Comment: wow - actually stating the obvious was indeed my problem - I did not configure the Date Format at NLS! What a shame thank you!!

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8134493/how-can-i-set-a-custom-date-time-format-in-oracle-sql-developer