# two date columns comparison oracle do not work as expected

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a query that involves a where clause which i compare two columns that have `DATE` as their data type. these are `last_collected_date` and `update_date`.

```
SELECT *
FROM mytable
WHERE last_collected_date < update_date;
```

The weird thing is that this does not work as expected and I get dates of `last_collected_date` that have the same day as `update_date`.

However when I use `to_date` function:

```
SELECT *
FROM mytable
WHERE to_date(last_collected_date) < to_date(update_date);
```

It works as expected. Why is that ? Does oracle convert dates into strings internally in a select statement ?

This is my NLS settings. Is that reason I dont see my `hh:mi:ss` ?

[image]

Comment: Regarding your edit "Is that reason I dont see my `hh:mi:ss`?" Yes, set the date format to `DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS` and you will see the date and time components.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`DATE` in Oracle is a misnomer; it is a datetime really. This means it always consists of a date and a time, and if we want to look at dates only, we set the time to midnight.

With

```
WHERE last_collected_date < update_date
```

you may be comparing 2023-02-27 09:00 with 2023-02-27 11:00. Same date, but the `WHERE` clause results in true, because of the different times.

This:

```
WHERE to_date(last_collected_date) < to_date(update_date)
```

is kind of dangerous, because of hidden implicit conversions, and only happens to work for you coincidentally. `TO_DATE` is a function applied on a string you want to convert to a datetime. What Oracle does is convert your datetimes to strings according to your session settings and then back to datetimes. Your session setting seems to be date-only, so you happen to lose the time part in the process and set your two dates to midnight thus.

If you want to compare dates, truncate the datetime to midnight:

```
WHERE last_collected_date < TRUNC(update_date)
```

Comment: why oracle does not show `hh:mi:ss` ? it's so misleading. how can i see this part of the date ?

Comment: This is a setting in the tool you are using to read the data. If you are using SQL Developer, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/8134646/2270762.

Answer (score 2):

When you do:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   mytable
WHERE  to_date(last_collected_date) < to_date(update_date);
```

Then `TO_DATE` expects a string as the first argument so your query is effectively:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   mytable
WHERE  TO_DATE(
         TO_CHAR(
           last_collected_date,
           (SELECT value FROM NLS_SESSION_PARAMETERS WHERE parameter = 'NLS_DATE_FORMAT')
         ),
         (SELECT value FROM NLS_SESSION_PARAMETERS WHERE parameter = 'NLS_DATE_FORMAT')
       )
       <
       TO_DATE(
         TO_CHAR(
           update_date,
           (SELECT value FROM NLS_SESSION_PARAMETERS WHERE parameter = 'NLS_DATE_FORMAT')
         ),
         (SELECT value FROM NLS_SESSION_PARAMETERS WHERE parameter = 'NLS_DATE_FORMAT')
       );
```

If your `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` is `DD-MON-RR` (or equivalent without a time component) then what you are effectively doing is truncating the string back to midnight.

If that is what you want then use `TRUNC`:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   mytable
WHERE  TRUNC(last_collected_date) < TRUNC(update_date);
```

*However, it is not clear why `last_collected_date < update_date` would not work but why `TRUNC(last_collected_date) < TRUNC(update_date)` would work as if `last_collected_date < update_date` is false then `TRUNC(last_collected_date) < TRUNC(update_date)` must also be false.*

Comment: Instead of `(SELECT value FROM NLS_SESSION_PARAMETERS WHERE parameter = 'NLS_DATE_FORMAT')` you could also write simple `SYS_CONTEXT('USERENV', 'NLS_DATE_FORMAT')` - but maybe your version is more frightened and prevents users to do this famous mistake.

Answer (score 1):

Oracle dates store both date and time.  So assuming the following data:

```
last_collected_date | update_date
2023-02-27 12:34:56 | 2023-02-27 23:00:00
```

Your first query would match to this data, because the last collected date is before the update date, despite both being on the same calendar day.

Comment: This would not be the cause as, assuming the `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` is `DD-MON-RR` (or equivalent) then `to_date(last_collected_date) < to_date(update_date)` will just truncate the dates to midnight and the comparison is `<` (not `<=`) so the rows would not match.

Comment: ok and `to_date` sets `hh:mi:ss` to zero ? that's why it works ? I don't see the `hh:mi:ss` when querying my data. why ?

Comment: i want to truncate everything to midnight. just want to get a day earlier. the funny thing is that i cannot even see the `hh:mi:ss` part when selecting the column

Comment: @moth *ok and to_date sets hh:mi:ss to zero ?* No, `to_date()` takes a string parameter, so when you pass something different it first has to convert that value into a string in order to proceed. Converting a date to a string without specifying how makes it fall back on the session NLS defaults, which might strip the time details or it might not.