# Add hardcoded timestamp to a column in Oracle sql

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have a column that has timestamp coming as follows

```
select grade_date from grades_vs
```

will give output

```
grade_date
2023-11-18T00:00:00.000+00:00
```

I want to change the timestamp part and hardcode it to `2023-11-18T04:36:16.000+00:00`.

Mainly add `'T04:36:16.000+00:00'` so that the time is exactly in this format instead of

```
00:00:00
```

I am using to_timestamp for this but it is giving me a literal string error. How can i hardcode this value and convert the column to timestamp ?

Comment: What data type is the column - varchar2, or timestamp, or timestamp with time zone? Also do you always want to set the time to the same value, 04:36:16, for all rows, regardless of the date part; and even if the time zone offset isn't +00:00? )And which version of Oracle are you using?)

Comment: data type is "DATE" and yes it should always be 04:36:16, regardless of the date part and th timezone as well

Comment: A `DATE` does not have a time zone.

Answer (score 0):

If your column is a DATE then it doesn't have fractional seconds or a time zone; or any intrinsic human-readable format. So the formatting, including those extra elements, is being hard-coded in the presentation of the data, possibly in your NLS settings:

```
alter session set nls_date_format = 'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS".000+00:00"'
```

or maybe directly by your client (or NLS settings set in SQL Developer, as you tagged that client).

Anyway... as it's a DATE not a VARCHAR2 data type you can set the time directly by adding an interval representing the hours, minutes and seconds you want. If you just want to see the modified values in a query then:

```
select grade_date + interval '04:36:16' hour to second as grade_date
from grade_vs
```

| GRADE_DATE |
| --- |
| 2023-11-18T04:36:16.000+00:00 |

or to reset any values with non-midnight times back to midnight first:

```
select trunc(grade_date) + interval '04:36:16' hour to second as grade_date
from grade_vs
```

| GRADE_DATE |
| --- |
| 2023-11-18T04:36:16.000+00:00 |

If you want to change the values in the table then you can update with the same calculation:

```
update grade_vs
set grade_date = grade_date + interval '04:36:16' hour to second;
```

or to reset any values with non-midnight times back to midnight first:

```
update grade_vs
set grade_date = trunc(grade_date) + interval '04:36:16' hour to second;
```

which gives you, using the NLS formatting above:

```
select * from grade_vs
```

| GRADE_DATE |
| --- |
| 2023-11-18T04:36:16.000+00:00 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/rO77rDTC)

---

Dates and timestamps are stored in an internal binary representation, which you don't normally need to worry about, but they are not stored as you are seeing them displayed.

If you were starting from a string value (which you aren't, fortunately) then you could convert that to a date (ignoring the fractional seconds and time zone offset; this assumes they are always zero):

```
alter session set nls_date_format = 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'
```

```
select to_date('2023-11-18T04:36:16.000+00:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS."000+00:00"') as result
from dual
```

| RESULT |
| --- |
| 2023-11-18 04:36:16 |

or to a timestamp (ignoring the time zone offset):

```
alter session set nls_timestamp_format = 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF3'
```

```
select to_timestamp('2023-11-18T04:36:16.000+00:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS.FF3"+00:00"') as result
from dual
```

| RESULT |
| --- |
| 2023-11-18 04:36:16.000 |

or to a timestamp with time zone:

```
alter session set nls_timestamp_tz_format = 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF3TZR'
```

```
select to_timestamp_tz('2023-11-18T04:36:16.000+00:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS.FF3TZH:TZM') as result
from dual
```

| RESULT |
| --- |
| 2023-11-18 04:36:16.000+00:00 |

```
-- only in recent versions of Oracle
select to_utc_timestamp_tz('2023-11-18T04:36:16.000+00:00') as result
from dual
```

| RESULT |
| --- |
| 2023-11-18 04:36:16.000+00:00 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/1KPgGs5q)

But again, that's only if you're starting from a string, which you are not.

Comment: I cannot change the NLS setting and cannot use the DMLs, in that case this change wont be feasible (since i am using Oracle cloud )

Comment: What do you mean? You're already seeing the data formatted like that. Also not sure what you mean about DML - just that you want to see the modified value in a query, but not update the table? It's the same calculation.

Comment: Right, it should be done in the select query using the functions as I cannot perform the update,delete etc

Answer (score 0):

In Oracle, `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE` is a binary data type that is **stored** as 14-20 bytes comprising 1-byte for century, year-of-century, month, day, hour, minute and second then 0-6 bytes for fractional seconds (depending on the precision you require) and 7 bytes for the time zone. It **ALWAYS** has these components and it is **NEVER** stored in any particular human-readable format.

> Mainly add `'T04:36:16.000+00:00'` so that the time is exactly in this format

Since a `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE` (and `DATE` and `TIMESTAMP`) are binary data-types and they are **NEVER** stored in any particular human-readable format then what you are asking is impossible because you cannot **store** a format.

If you want to **display** (not store) the timestamp in a particular format then use `TO_CHAR` to convert it to a formatted string and use double quotes to hard-code part of the format model:

```sql
SELECT TO_CHAR(grade_date, 'YYYY-MM-DD"T04:36:16.000"TZR') AS grade_date
FROM   grades_vs
```

Which, for the sample data:

```
CREATE TABLE grades_vs (grade_date) AS
SELECT TIMESTAMP '2023-11-18 00:00:00.000+00:00' FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

| GRADE_DATE |
| --- |
| 2023-11-18T04:36:16.000+00:00 |

---

If you want to return a `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE` (and not a string) then you can subtract the current time component and add an `INTERVAL DAY TO SECOND` to set the new time component:

```sql
SELECT grade_date
         - (grade_date - TRUNC(grade_date))       -- Current time component
         + INTERVAL '04:36:16.000' HOUR TO SECOND -- New time component
       AS grade_date
FROM   grades_vs
```

Which will modify the time component while leaving the date and time zone components as-is. However, you are then relying on the client application (i.e. SQL Developer) to format the value for you (and not the database).

If the client is set to display `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE` data-types using the format `YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS.FF3TZR` then the output is:

| GRADE_DATE |
| --- |
| 2023-11-18T04:36:16.000+00:00 |

But this relies on you setting the client application up with the correct format.

With SQL Developer, you can [change date and timestamp formatting options in the client settings](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8134493/1509264) using, for `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE` either:

```sql
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_TIMESTAMP_TZ_FORMAT = 'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS.FF3TZR';
```

Or through the menu changing the preferences and the `Database > NLS > Timestamp TZ Format` setting.

---

If your column is a `DATE` (and not a `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE`) then it is also a binary data type that is stored using 7-bytes for 1-byte for century, year-of-century, month, day, hour, minute and second. Again, it **ALWAYS** contains all those components and it is **NEVER** stored in any particular format.

A `DATE` will not include a time zone so you can use the same query as before but you will have to hard-code the time zone as well:

```sql
SELECT TO_CHAR(grade_date, 'YYYY-MM-DD"T04:36:16.000+00:00"') AS grade_date
FROM   grades_vs
```

and if you want a `DATE` (not string) then, again, you can mostly repeat the previous query (with a minor modification):

```sql
SELECT grade_date
         - (grade_date - TRUNC(grade_date)) DAY TO SECOND
         + INTERVAL '04:36:16.000' HOUR TO SECOND
       AS grade_date
FROM   grades_vs
```

but you can simplify it to:

```sql
SELECT TRUNC(grade_date) + INTERVAL '04:36:16' HOUR TO SECOND
       AS grade_date
FROM   grades_vs
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/LyWsX5pc)